# Getting the direction the user is facing using Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, core-location

I'm trying to indicate to the user the direction that he is facing in the form of N,S,E,W,NE,SE,SW,NW shown on a label. Whenever the user changes his physical direction, the label would update to the current direction.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Swift 5.2**

You can do this with the `CoreLocation` framework.

1. Conform to the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` protocol
2. Instantiate an instance of `CLLocationManager` and set the delegate as self
3. You do not need user permissions if you just need the heading (and not actual user location)
4. Tell the `CLLocationManager` to start updating the heading
5. The heading will be reported back to the delegate method `didUpdateHeading`
6. Use a switch statement to find cardinal direction based on the input degrees.
7. Update your label

---

```
import CoreLocation
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet var directionLabel: UILabel!

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
        directionLabel.text = cardinalValue(from: newHeading.trueHeading)
    }
    
    func cardinalValue(from heading: CLLocationDirection) -> String {
        switch heading {
        case 0 ..< 22.5:
            return "N"
        case 22.5 ..< 67.5:
            return "NE"
        case 67.5 ..< 112.5:
            return "E"
        case 112.5 ..< 157.5:
            return "SE"
        case 157.5 ..< 202.5:
            return "S"
        case 202.5 ..< 247.5:
            return "SW"
        case 247.5 ..< 292.5:
            return "W"
        case 292.5 ..< 337.5:
            return "NW"
        case 337.5 ... 360.0:
            return "N"
        default:
            return ""
        }
    }
}
```

---

The heading from the delegate can be accessed as either `.magneticHeading` or `.trueHeading`

> **Magnetic Heading**
>
> The value in this property represents the heading relative to the
> magnetic North Pole, which is different from the geographic North
> Pole. The value 0 means the device is pointed toward magnetic north,
> 90 means it is pointed east, 180 means it is pointed south, and so on.
> The value in this property should always be valid.
>
> **True Heading**
>
> The value in this property represents the heading relative to the
> geographic North Pole. The value 0 means the device is pointed toward
> true north, 90 means it is pointed due east, 180 means it is pointed
> due south, and so on. A negative value indicates that the heading
> could not be determined.

Comment: How would a heading of 22.53 be handled?

Comment: Thank you for this! That's exactly what I needed. But when I try to run this code in a playground, the function locationManager never gets called and the label doesn't show anything. How do I fix this?

Comment: and you can check whether heading information is available on whichever device you are running with `CLLocationManager.headingAvailable()` // returns a Boolean

Comment: I'm running it on Playgrounds on an iPad and the CLLocationManager.headingAvailable() returns true.

Comment: try `PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true`

Comment: Same problem. I'm probably missing something way too basic. I don't think the label is added to the view?

Comment: I also added a print("ran") in the locationManager but it never runs

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about Playgrounds on iPad.  The code I provided for you works when installed on a live device.